# Ball in cavas leaves a trace on animation and overdraws other objects on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm making a small game in js where I move a ball on device orientation change. When the ball moves it leaves a trace, I tried to do it with `clearRect()` but it was overdrawing the rest of things in the canvas. Because of this problem functions `checkForWinningHole()` and `checkForLosingHole()` don't work.
Is there any way to make the ball move and don't leave a trace behind?

```js
// event listeners
document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click', startGame);
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', onDeviceOrientationChange, true);

// properties and objects
let canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let speedX = 0;
let speedY = 0;
let minute = 0;
let second = 0;
const holes = [];
let gameIsOn = false;
let cw = canvas.width;
let ch = canvas.height;
const score = document.querySelectorAll('.score');
let color;
const ball = {
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    r: 10,
    speedX: 0,
    speedY: 0
};

const hole = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    r: 25
};

// functions

function startGame(){
    gameIsOn = true;
    drawHoles();
    drawWinningHole();
    function play(){
        drawBall();
        checkForWinnningHole();
        checkForLosingHole();
    }           
    setInterval(play, 16);
        
}

function drawBall(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = ' rgb(206, 36, 6)';
    ctx.arc(
        ball.x,
        ball.y, 
        ball.r, 
        0, 
        2 * Math.PI,
        false
    );
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    
    moveBall();
}



function drawHoles(){
    color = 'rgb(84, 93, 139)';
    for (let i = 1; i < canvas.width/80; i++) { 
        let hx =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width - hole.r * 2 + 1)) ;
        let hy =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.height - hole.r * 2 +1));
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(
            hx,
            hy,
            hole.r,
            0,
            2 * Math.PI,
            false
        );
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
        holes.push({
            h: ctx,
            c: color
        });
    }   

}

function drawWinningHole(){
    color = 'rgb(255, 255, 0)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(
        Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width - hole.r * 2 + 1)),
        Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.height - hole.r * 2 +1)),
        hole.r,
        0,
        2 * Math.PI,
        false
    );
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 0)';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    holes.push({
        h: ctx,
        c: color
    });
    console.log(holes);
}

function moveBall(){
    if(ball.x + speedX < cw - 30 && ball.x + speedX > 20){ 
        ball.x += speedX;      
    }
    if(ball.y + speedY < ch - 30 && ball.y + speedY > 20){
        ball.y += speedY;       
    }
}

function onDeviceOrientationChange(ev){
    speedX = ev.gamma/35; 
    speedY = ev.beta/35;
}


function checkForWinnningHole(){
    holes.forEach(({
        ctx, 
        color
    }) => {
        if (color === 'rgb(255, 255, 0)' && ball.x >= ctx.x && ball.y >= ctx.y
                    && ball.y <= ctx.y + hole.r * 2 && ball.x <= ctx.x + hole.r * 2)  
        {
            gameIsOn = false;
            ball.speedX = 0;
            ball.speedY = 0;
            ball.x = 0;
            score.innerHTML = '1';
        }       
    });
}

function checkForLosingHole(){
    holes.forEach(({
        ctx, 
        color
    }) => {
        if (color === 'rgb(84, 93, 139)' && ball.x >= ctx.x && ball.y >= ctx.y && ball.y <= ctx.y + hole.r * 2 && ball.x <= ctx.x + hole.r * 2) 
        {
            gameIsOn = false;
            ball.speedX = 0;
            ball.speedY = 0;
            ball.x = 0;
            ball.y = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ball in the hole</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas class="canvas" width="700" height="700" ></canvas>    
    <div class="info">
        <button class="start">START GAME</button>
        <span>SCORE:</span>
        <span class="score">0</span>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why you are storing your rendering context in your hole objects. I also think a more normal approach to creating this game would be to draw every one of your sprites every frame. It would take more processing power but with a game this size that is hardly a concern

Answer (score 0):

You are painting background once and the multiple times ball, so the 'old' ball shape is never removed, all you need to chanage:

```
function startGame(){
    gameIsOn = true;
    function play(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //clear canvas
        drawHoles();
        drawWinningHole(); // redraw holes
        drawBall(); // draw ball with new position
        checkForWinnningHole();
        checkForLosingHole();
    }           
    setInterval(play, 16);
        
}
```

Now all you holes are every 10 ms draw in new positions, sou you have to calculate holes positions once at the begging of the game (it is important), and draw them with the same positions every time.

So for winning hole calculate position on top on you file:

```
const winingHoleX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width - hole.r * 2 + 1))
const winingHoleY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.height - hole.r * 2 +1))
```

And draw function:

```
function drawWinningHole(){
    color = 'rgb(255, 255, 0)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(
        winingHoleX,
        winingHoleY,
        hole.r,
        0,
        2 * Math.PI,
        false
    );
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 0)';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    holes.push({
        h: ctx,
        c: color
    });
    console.log(holes);
}
```

For other holes it should looks similar :)

I hope I helped!

Comment: thanks for the answer, the problem is that the function drawHoles() is executed every 16ms and everytime they spawn in a different place :(

Comment: Yes, you have to do changes in drawHoles(), similar to changes I did in drawWinningHole(). If you need help with that function

Comment: I have made another function initHoles() where I only initialize an object with random cordinates and it worked!